# Encrypt or partially encrypt Core Data database?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, encryption

I was wondering...
Is it possible to encrypt parts of or all of an existing Core Data application's database without losing features or relying deeply on third-party dependencies?

We could "roll our own" encryption because these particular fields do not need to be queried (it's metadata or binary data) ... but I don't want to affect the other parts of the database nor break everything that is already working.

We could also encrypt the whole DB. Not sure what is best.

Comment: What you want to do is just encrypt some particular fields in some tables of your database? or do you need to protect the whole BD? for example, DB will be encrypted at the file level ?

Comment: It's more just obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you create the persistent store , in the options parameter you can specify the NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey  with NSFileProtectionComplete value , this will encrypt the database file when the device is locked and passcode is set, that should be good enough for operational data (not passwords and secrets).
2. Save sensitive data like client secrets and passwords in the keychain , not in the database , database encryption hack is a matter of time.

Comment: The purpose is to obfuscate, not just to protect the data while the device is locked.

Comment: Then you will need to use some 3rd party , there is no build in obfuscation.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for encrypting strings on iOS, ideally seamlessly with Core Data? Not sure if anything exists without swapping out the persistent store with something like this... https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data  ... which unfortunately does not support certain features.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Oleg posted, you can store binary data in a Core Data `NSManagedObject`.  You can then encrypt your string and store it in that binary property.

The performance is poor and the property is not searchable at the store level (you can search once you have fetched since it would be unencrypted in memory) but it is doable.